# Unity3D gameObject tag not working for me

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this line of code, but when i run this in unity it destroys itself when comes to contact with anything, but i want to do this only when with contact with the Player. I am sure that the player tag has been assigned correctly. I'm a beginner so it's probably something very dumb. Thank you for any help!

```
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) ;
    {
        Debug.Log("collision w/ " + other.gameObject.name);
        theScore += 50;
        scoreText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "SCORE: " + theScore;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

Comment: **This is a typo! (And thereby off-topic)** You have a `;` after `if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) ;` so the following code block is executed **always**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the statements are all correct. You just added one too many `;` behind the if-statement. If-Statements do not need a `;` since the `{...}` ends the statements.

The correct code is hence:

```
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) //no semicolon here
{
    Debug.Log("collision w/ " + other.gameObject.name);
    theScore += 50;
    scoreText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "SCORE: " + theScore;
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)

Comment: Also note that `{...}` is just wrapping a code block .. it isn't actually part of the `if` statement itself ;) By using the `;` you also end a single line expression so basically `if(...) ;` equals `if(...){ }`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are not supposed to add a `;` after an `if` statement.

```
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) //no semicolon here
{
    Debug.Log("collision w/ " + other.gameObject.name);
    theScore += 50;
    scoreText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "SCORE: " + theScore;
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

And if you have to destroy the gameObject collided with, then replace :

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

With:

```
Destroy(other.gameObject);
```